# Prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is normal if and only if $\frac{|f'(z)|}{1+|f(z)|^2}\le C_K$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of analytic functions on $B(0,1)\subset \mathbb{C}$. Prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is normal if and only if for every compact subset $K\subset B(0,1)\subset \mathbb{C}$ there is a constant $C_K>0$ such that $$\frac{|f'(z)|}{1+|f(z)|^2}\le C_K$$ for all  $f\in\mathcal{F}$.

Could anyone give some help? I am really struggling solving this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: See Ahlfors's book Complex Analysis, second edition p.218, Theorem 14.

Comment: @ts375_zk26 Thank you so much!